# how to change the when-to-predict-one parameter in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

As we know, in logistic regression algorithm we predict one when theta times X is bigger than 0.5. I wanna raise the precision value. so i wanna change the predict function to predict 1 when theta times X is bigger than 0.7 or other values bigger than 0.5.

If i write the algorithm i could easily do it. But with sklearn package, i have no idea what to do.

Anyone can give me a hand?

To explain the question clearly enough, here is the predict function wroten in octave:

```
p = sigmoid(X*theta);

for i=1:size(p)(1)
    if p(i) >= 0.6
        p(i) = 1;
    else
        p(i) = 0;
    endif;
endfor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LogisticRegression` predictor object from sklearn has a `predict_proba` method which outputs the probabilities that an input example belongs to a certain class. You can use this function along with your own defined theta times X to get the functionality you desire.

An example:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1337)  # Seed random for reproducibility
X = np.random.random((10, 5))  # Create sample data
Y = np.random.randint(2, size=10)

lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(X, Y)

prob_example_is_one = lr.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]

my_theta_times_X = 0.7  # Our custom threshold
predict_greater_than_theta = prob_example_is_one > my_theta_times_X
```

Here's the docstring for `predict_proba`:

```
Probability estimates.

The returned estimates for all classes are ordered by the
label of classes.

For a multi_class problem, if multi_class is set to be "multinomial"
the softmax function is used to find the predicted probability of
each class.
Else use a one-vs-rest approach, i.e calculate the probability
of each class assuming it to be positive using the logistic function.
and normalize these values across all the classes.

Parameters
----------
X : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]

Returns
-------
T : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_classes]
    Returns the probability of the sample for each class in the model,
    where classes are ordered as they are in ``self.classes_``.
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for both binary and multi-class classification:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np

#X = some training data
#y = labels for training data
#X_test = some test data

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X, y)

predictions = clf.predict_proba(X_test)

predictions = clf.classes_[np.argmax(predictions > threshold, axis=1)]
```